# Fetch DateTime CRM 2011

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Im having some trouble with DateTime: Using Fetch

```
  <attribute name='new_startdate' groupby='true' dategrouping='day' alias='new_startdate' /> 
  <attribute name='new_enddate' groupby='true' dategrouping='day' alias='new_enddate' /> 
  <attribute name='new_duedate' groupby='true' dategrouping='day' alias='new_duedate' />
```

Think this is the bit thats Wrong....

```
  DateTime scheduledstart = ((DateTime)((AliasedValue)a["new_startdate"]).Value);
  tracer.Trace("DateTime 1 Done");
  DateTime enddate = ((DateTime)((AliasedValue)a["new_enddate"]).Value);
  tracer.Trace("DateTime 2 Done");
  DateTime scheduledend = ((DateTime)((AliasedValue)a["new_duedate"]).Value);
```

Then i add to the new Entity...

```
    if (scheduledstart != null)
    {
      Activity.Attributes.Add("scheduledstart", scheduledstart);
    }
    if (enddate != null)
    {
       Activity.Attributes.Add("scheduledend", enddate);
    }
    if (scheduledend != null)
    {
     Activity.Attributes.Add("scheduledend", scheduledend);
    }
```

Any Ideas How i write the DateTime using AliasedValue from fetch? or a better way to do this>

Thanks

Comment: I read this... think its the same issue... When you read any CRM DateTime value using OData Service, the value comes in “/Date(1314763200000)/“ format, which we can’t directly set to DateTime field. http://rajeevpentyala.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/read-odata-service-date-field-in-crm-2011/. How would i do the concversion from a Fetch using AliasedValue?

Comment: What is the error or problem?

Comment: if it's aliased, you would do result["<alias>.<field>"]; you can see this better if you debug into your code and look through the result.attributes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I have decided to just use a seperate fetch for the date values

```
string Date_Gather = string.Format(@"         
      <fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
         <entity name='new_import'>                       
                 <attribute name='new_enddate'/>         
         </entity>
       </fetch>", entity.Id);

foreach (var b in Date_Gather_result.Entities)
{

   if (b.Attributes.Contains("new_enddate"))
      {
          enddate = ((DateTime)(b["new_enddate"]));
          Entity.Attributes.Add("scheduledend", enddate);
      }
}
```

Thanks anyway hope it helps others

Comment: Also, why fetchXml instead of query expression?

Answer (score 1):

I used to hate dealing with aliased values, but then I wrote some extension methods and now I don't worry about them any more.  Check out my blog [Simplifying Retrieval of Aliased Values in CRM 2011](http://www.dotnetdust.blogspot.com/2013/03/simplifying-retrieval-of-aliased-values.html).  I'm thinking it'll help solve your current problem.

Comment: Yeah thats useful, I am looking at dates and seems to be an issue, down to "dategrouping" i have learnt that CRM brings the date in as Int32, im hoping that there is a better way then dategrouping "day" "month" "year" and putting it all back together. i have tried to convert to datetime but then crm dosent like the format from plugin... & cant pass int32 to datetime field.

Comment: @RichardDewhirst I've never used DateGrouping before.  So (AliasedValue)a["new_duedate"]).Value is an int?  What example values are you seeing?  Is your problem converting the int into a DateTime?

Comment: +1 for promoting EMs. Also, did you get the message about licensing I've sent you? And for some reason I can't follow your blog... :(

Comment: @KonradViltersten I haven't posted an entry to my blog in over 2 years before today... Is it giving you an error message?  I don't remember the message on licensing...